# Client Server over shared Public IP address?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I am writing my own Chat application that uses the Server Client model over TCP. It is just for own learning.

When I connect over local networks, there is no hitch. This I understand as the other local IPs are directly available. Example: 192.168.1.28 connect to server 192.168.1.90

Then I tried to move is to connect over the internet.

I have set up my router to port forward tcp connections to my server on 192.168.1.90 through port 4296.

Then I look for my router's public IP address. it shows 101.1.1.20

Then I setup my client in another friend's PC with another connection. And executeby connecting Client to IP: 101.1.1.20 on port 4296

It fails....

Upon further investigation, it seems my router's public IP is a SHARED PUBLIC IP. Which would mean there is another layer on top of my router I suppose

Any tips on where to go further on this? I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like http://www.whatismyip.com/, which can tell you the public IP address that is seen by others when you connect to them.

This might not be enough to allow you to connect from the outside (since it's possible that something is configured to block all incoming connections), but it would at least let you see whether your router's IP is the same as the way the outside world sees you.

You might also want to try swapping the byte order on your port, as that's something people often get wrong in their client and/or server program, and if you got it wrong on both for a local port, it would work there but not through your router if you configured the port to match (so since 4296 == 0x10c8, also try checking port 0xc810 == 51216 while your router is configured for 4296).

Also worth trying to connect with telnet instead of your own client just to see if the connection succeeds, since there's fewer things that are probably wrong. Also using something like wireshark (or tcpdump) can tell you whether any SYN packet is arriving at your server side when you try this.

Comment: Well. The router ip I obtained is from what is my ip. It is what the external world sees me as. But trying to connect to that ip to reach my server yields nothing . My suspicion would be because the publicly seen ip is a shared ip?

Comment: Usually the publicly available IP is unique to your connection to the ISP, so if your router is configured to pass along the connections on that port, it will pass the SYN packet.

Comment: I checked my router.... it states itself is another IP different from the public ip from whatismyip. hmm